# Selenium webdriver element identification fails on machine-generated webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am facing a problem identifying elements on an webpage generated by a machine. I am using Selenium Webdriver for Java and Google Chrome as browser.

So, there are ids and values that look very unusually. I tried to identify the elements by id and xpath so far. Here's some code to my problem.

The select box i want to identify:

```
<select id="singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:VPP001_Person" class="form-control" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="lbl_192_982637" aria-describedby="singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:VPP001_Person_Sth"><option aria-selected="false" disabled="" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true"></option><option id="singleselect-option-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:VPP001_Person[0]" value="OK" aria-selected="false">Ja, die Gehaltsnachweise liegen vor</option><option id="singleselect-option-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:VPP001_Person[1]" value="NOK" aria-selected="false">Ja, es bestehen aber Formmängel</option><option id="singleselect-option-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:VPP001_Person[2]" value="NO" aria-selected="false">Nein, die Gehaltsnachweise liegen nicht vor</option><option id="singleselect-option-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:VPP001_Person[3]" value="WAIVER" aria-selected="false">Unterlagsverzicht</option></select>
```

Full XPath is:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/select
```

The relative xPath is:

```
//*[@id="singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:VPP001_Person"]
```

Idetification by id ("singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:VPP001_Person") fails also like by xpath, even that the xpath entered in Google Chrome is valid:

[image]

Unfortunately i cannot post the whole html page but maybe someone has a clue here. Its a big page, maybe the scrolling is the problem as not all items are visible art once in window?

### Last try from first comment (checked the preconditions 1/1)

[image]

Translated into Java:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select[id^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:'][aria-describedby^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout']")));
        WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:'][aria-describedby^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout']"));
```

...fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: select[id^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:'][aria-describedby^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at com.commerzbank.test.tool.service.e2e.ChromeTest.main(ChromeTest.java:74)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"select[id^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:'][aria-describedby^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout']"}
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long research, short answer. The issue have been some very deep nested iframes, two in my specitfic case, on my big web page. I solved it with the following code snippet:

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@title, 'Manual')]")));
        WebElement parentFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@title, 'Manual')]"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(parentFrame);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@title, 'Test')]"))));
        WebElement childFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@title, 'Test')]"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(childFrame);
```

After switching to the child iframe i could find my element. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if the below CSS:

```
select[id^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:'][aria-describedby^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout']
```

is unique in HTMLDOM or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

if it is unique, I would recommend you to try it with explicit waits.

**Code:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[id^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout2:QuestionGroup1[0]:QuestionGroup:Vertical_Layout1:Question1[0]:Question:Horizontal_Layout1:'][aria-describedby^='singleselect-Vertical_Layout']"))))
select.select_by_value('NOK')
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Checked all preconditions, all ok. But it failed also (will comment it above).

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: See above in original post. There i commted your approach under: Last try from first comment (checked the preconditions 1/1)

Comment: Looks like it's in iframe.. can you share but outer and up htm from this mode ?

Comment: What do you need? The whole html? I cannot post it here, its too long and company related infos in there... But i want to give you as much i can.

Comment: I mentioned what I did mention above i.e: outerHTML from this node to verify if we have got an iframe

Comment: Yes we have at least two iframes somewhere in the outer. Is sooo long. I can send it to you personally but not here i think.

Comment: As far as I know here at StackOverflow, you can share all the details, not sure if you can send it to me personally. btw you can get my email from my bio here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241488/discussion-between-bernado-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: Sent you the html. Will edit the html to be able to add it here too.